# Php/Pdo insert not working: syntax error?

Tags: php, syntax, pdo

I'm writing some code to enter some data into a mysql dtabase using PDO. This code works (verifying that the data is all there):

```
echo $usertype . '<br>';
echo $firstname . '<br>';
echo $lastname . '<br>';
echo $company . '<br>';
echo $jobtitle . '<br>';
echo $address . '<br>';
echo $email . '<br>';
echo $telephone . '<br>';
echo $mobile . '<br>';
echo $dobday . '<br>';
echo $dobmonth . '<br>';
echo $dobyear . '<br>';
echo $gender . '<br>';
echo $ethnicity . '<br>';
echo $password . '<br>';
echo $credits . '<br>';
```

but this code doesn't (I've checked the database connection and it does connect and the table called users does exist):

```
$STH = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, company, jobtitle, usertype, address, email, telephone, mobile, dobday, dobmonth, dobyear, gender, ethnicity, password, credits) values (:firstname, :lastname, :company, :jobtitle, :usertype, :address, :email, :telephone, :mobile, :dobday, :dobmonth, :dobyear :gender, :ethnicity, :password, :credits)");
$STH->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
$STH->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
$STH->bindParam(':company', $company);
$STH->bindParam(':jobtitle', $jobtitle);
$STH->bindParam(':usertype', $usertype);
$STH->bindParam(':address', $address);
$STH->bindParam(':email', $email);
$STH->bindParam(':telephone', $telephone);
$STH->bindParam(':mobile', $mobile);
$STH->bindParam(':dobday', $dobday);
$STH->bindParam(':dobmonth', $dobmonth);
$STH->bindParam(':dobyear', $dobyear);
$STH->bindParam(':gender', $gender);
$STH->bindParam(':ethnicity', $ethnicity);
$STH->bindParam(':password', $password);
$STH->bindParam(':credits', $credits);
try{
    $STH->execute();
    redirect_to(formsuccess.php);
    }
catch(PDOException $e) { 
    echo "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.";  
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
    redirect_to(databaseentryfail.php); 

    }
```

Please can you help me with this, I know it's something silly that I've missed...

Hoxton

Comment: `redirect_to(formsuccess.php);` is invalid code. What you're parsing is the constant named `formsuccess` and a constant named `php` concatenated. Use quotes: `redirect_to('formsuccess.php');`

Comment: @h2ooooooo but that doesn't cause a syntax error. Which version of PHP are you using? And what's the actual error?

Comment: @joonty I know - the syntax error is a missing comma - this was just adding onto the problems.

Comment: If you are writing the exception into a text file – then why don’t you go and look what it says in there …?

Comment: @joonty - Parse errors are not the only thing that invalid code can cause. This question is kind of crazy—the OP has put a lot of effort to hide the debugging information generated by PHP xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a comma between `:dobyear` and `:gender`:

> $STH = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, company, jobtitle, usertype, address, email, telephone, mobile, dobday, dobmonth, dobyear, gender, ethnicity, password, credits) values (:firstname, :lastname, :company, :jobtitle, :usertype, :address, :email, :telephone, :mobile, :dobday, :dobmonth, **:dobyear :gender**, :ethnicity, :password, :credits)");

Comment: It's worth noting that these kind of SQL syntax errors trigger a `PDOException` and `$e->getMessage()` shows the exact cause of the error. While the original code uses exceptions, it's clear that the OP is not fully sure of their purpose.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario You'd get a syntax error and unfortunately not "there's a comma missing between `:dobyear` and `:gender`". Best case you get a line number which in this case would be 0 or 1 (can't remember if it's 0-indexed)

Answer (score 2):

Not replacing h2ooooooo 's great spot and reply, but just to say you will likely make this same mistake over and again.  One way to avoid that and is to make your code more readable by formatting it so:

```
$STH = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (
  firstname
, lastname
, company
, jobtitle
etc
```

Yes it means more LOC but it also leads to less time being spend chasing stupid errors because the lack of a leading comma will jump off the page at you.

There is another slight benefit in that you can very easily spot your SQL statements on the page.

(yeah, this is a comment not an answer, but its the only way I could illustrate my point)

Comment: I appreciate this as an addition to h2ooooooo's excellent answer: This is how everyone should format their statements to avoid the problem I had.

Comment: Glad you appreciated it! Thx.